# Ubuntu installer can't find any disk on Dell XPS 13 9350

Tags: system-installation, dell, disk

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 / 15.10 on my Dell XPS 13 9350 (November 2015).

I created a bootable USB disk which boots fine but the installer and the file manager do not detect the hard drive.

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

1. In Windows, run Command Prompt as admin
2. Invoke a Safe Mode boot with the command: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
3. Restart the PC and enter your BIOS during bootup.
4. Change from IDE to AHCI mode then `Save & Exit`.
5. Windows 10 will launch in Safe Mode.
6. Right click the Window icon and select to run the Command Prompt in Admin mode from among the various options.
7. Cancel Safe Mode booting with the command: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
8. Restart your PC once more and this time it will boot up normally but with AHCI mode activated.

([Source](http://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/15006-attn-ssd-owners-enabling-ahci-mode-after-windows-10-installation-5.html))

Comment: This saved my day. However I stuck on i/o err.

Comment: This is a good solution but only if you have Windows 10 installed already unfortunately...

Comment: The Live USB was able to detect my hard drive and do the install after only running steps 1-4...

Comment: I'm stuck at step 5) since now instead of the PIN, it does not recognize my password. Any idea how I can stop it from booting in safe mode?

Comment: In my case there was AHCI and RAID ON options in BIOS and it also worked.

Comment: In step 2 I get the error "The set command specified is not valid. The parameter is incorrect"

Comment: @Erel You might have just made a typo. But in any case, you could instead enable "Safe boot - Minimal" on the Boot tab of `msconfig.exe`, which does the same thing.

Comment: @Adrian IIRC, you can go to the Windows Recovery Environment, get a command prompt, then run `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot` to get out of safe mode. If you need more info, ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) since Windows support questions are off-topic here.

Comment: you also want to be aware that if you haven't set a local password you may never be able to get back in ... (esp if your network stuff wont work even when you do safe mode with networking ...)

Comment: @hg8 the steps on windows are required only if you want to keep windows booting - for linux just changing the bios to AHCI is enough

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi if you use powershell you need to enclose `{current}` in quotes, i.e. such as `"{current}"`, because brackets are interpreted by powershell as special characters

Comment: Same problem with a Dell XPS 13 7390, and this solution worked as charm (except that the SATA setting was "RAID" instead of "IDE". Changed it to AHCI, as indicated.

Answer (score 61):

So far the only workaround I found is to switch to AHCI Sata mode in BIOS settings:

1. Boot into BIOS (<kbd>F12</kbd> at startup)
2. Select **Bios Setup**.
3. Move to **System Configuration** > **SATA Operation** and select **AHCI**.

Restart the computer and now the Ubuntu installer will detect the SSD.

Unfortunately this is not practical for a dual boot setup as Windows won't be able to boot in SATA mode so you every time will have to revert the BIOS settings when wanting to boot Windows.

Comment: @cl-netbox Indeed, unfortunately the pre-installed Windows is not in AHCI mode...

Comment: You can create the boot recovery USB thumb drive, boot from there and repair windows install by choosing to "keep your personal files". Then windows will boot again in AHCI mode.

Comment: I did switch it, but ubuntu 16.xx still does not see the ssd.

Comment: It also works in the new dell xps 15

Comment: It was already in AHCI mode, but for some reason this did end up working

Comment: This worked for Dell Inspiron 7591

Comment: This also works with Dell Precision 3541. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

The main problem is that DELL shipped with Windows pre-installed in **IDE** mode. The best solution in every aspect is to perform a **clean installation of Windows**. As a side effect you achieve one big advantage: pure Windows without any crap.

1. Create a Windows system backup before. Things may break badly!
2. Boot from a **GParted Live media** and format the Windows partition with **ntfs**.
3. Boot into BIOS/UEFI of the PC and change the settings to **AHCI/SATA** mode.
4. Reinstall Windows.
5. Disable **Hibernation** and **Fast startup** in Windows
6. Boot from Ubuntu installation media and reinstall GRUB.
7. Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu to be the default operating system to boot. Now you can select which system to boot, without having to change settings.

For those users who don't want to reinstall Windows, there is a way to switch to AHCI mode:

- [Windows Vista and 7](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/61869-ahci-enable-windows-7-vista.html)
- [Windows 8/8.1 and 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/22631-enable-ahci-windows-8-windows-10-after-installation.html)

Comment: so Windows install first, followed by Ubuntu install ?

Comment: @toine : Yes, it is recommended to first install Windows and afterwards Ubuntu. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on an old HP Compaq & it was due to RAID format. I remove this in the BIOS menu:

- press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> on te startup & then quckly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> one the Intel BIOS screen
- Go in "Remove RAID" section & select your Hard Drive
- exit from BIOS & then reboot
- Hard drive should be visible from your Ubuntu installer