# Ubuntu Gnome 15.10-16.04 Dell XPS15 9530: Bluetooth doesn' work

Tags: dell, bluetooth, ubuntu-gnome, xps

Device loaded  with Ubuntu Gnome works perfectly with one exception: bluetooth. I cannot get any response from Broadcom 4352. Tried to replace driver ([see there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709794/dell-xps-13-9350-compatibility)) -no success. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You say It works perfectly with Ubuntu Gnome, but it doesn't work. Please decide on whether it works or not and clarify this by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Following the instructions [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317843) helped me get bluetooth working. Namely downloading the missing firmware file.

Comment: See the answer on this post for the simplest method I found for getting bluetooth working on my Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 16.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/880745/ubuntu-16-04-bluetooth-not-working-dell-xps13/920803#920803

Answer (score -2):

Replacement firmware with newer driver solved the problem (see for instance [here](http://tech.sybreon.com/2015/03/15/xps13-9343-ubuntu-linux/)). Just be careful with names: The new driver should have the same name as the old one.

Comment: And this was not enough : I still could not create device for headphone.  Temporary solution see http://askubuntu.com/questions/689281/pulseaudio-can-not-load-bluetooth-module-15-10. It works now, but it's a hack...