# Wireless adapter Broadcom [14e4:43a3] does not work in Ubuntu

Tags: 15.10, broadcom

I followed the instructions in the answer of

[Dell XPS 13 (9350) Compatibility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709794/dell-xps-13-9350-compatibility)

to solve the problem of not-working wifi (broadcom BCM4350) on my Dell XPS 13 (9350) with fresh installed Ubuntu 15.10.

After unzipping I follow the commands detailed in the answer. The first

```
sudo chown root:root brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd
```

returns

```
chown: changing ownership of 'brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of 'BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd': Operation not permitted
```

The following command line

```
sudo mv -t /lib/firmware/brcm/ BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
```

works fine, while

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.3.0-wifitest-custom_4.3.0-wifitest-custom-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb linux-image-4.3.0-wifitest-custom_4.3.0-wifitest-custom-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb
```

returns

```
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.3.0-wifitest-custom cannot be found. Please install the linux-headers-4.3.0-wifitest-custom package, or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
```

Any help is appreciated since I'm a real noob concerning Linux.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43a3] (rev 08), subsystem: dell device [1028:0021]

Comment: It is supported by kernel 4.4. I will write an answer.

Comment: Do you have a wired connection to internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adapter is not supported by Ubuntu stable kernels.

A way to get it work is to install a 4.4 kernel from Ubuntu 16.04 branch.

Connect to internet by wire and run in terminal

```
mkdir linux-4.4
cd linux-4.4
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-4.4.0-8-generic_4.4.0-8.23_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-extra-4.4.0-8-generic_4.4.0-8.23_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.4.0-8-generic_4.4.0-8.23_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.4.0-8_4.4.0-8.23_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.156_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Then reboot and test the wifi.

The kernel files are a subject of updates. The links will need to be updated. [Ubuntu packages search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) can be used to get the correct links

**Update:** For Ubuntu 14.04 users the 4.4 kernel can be installed by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

But dkms packages will not build with this kenel, if gcc 4.9+ is not installed.

Comment: Is it stable to update the kernel to the version 4.4 ?

Comment: This is a stable kernel. And you have no option

Comment: Well, i can use a wifi usb key until the next stable version of ubuntu will come out otherwise.

Comment: Well, it is your choice. It is the matter off opinions. Kernel 4.4 has been released as stable. Another option is to wait till 16.04 is released.

Comment: And you can always revert to the original kernel.

Comment: what do you suggest? new kernel?

Comment: If you need the wifi now, then install that kernel. If you can wait, then wait. It is obvious. But I need to update links.

Comment: The funniest thing is that you already tried to install a custom kernel that was built by someone. It is not stable in any meaning. And you ask "is the official Ubuntu kernel stable". That is really funny. You run any commands you find in the net without knowing the meaning and talk about stability.

Comment: as i wrote i'm a newbie, i'm trying to learn something about linux, for this reason i ask something here, and it's not easy since there are plenty of proposed solutions. After that, i didn't know that kernel 4.4 is the official ubuntu kernel. Sorry for the ignorance, and if it is that funny for you that i ask stupid questions, well, do not reply the next time.

Comment: There was no offence sry. I just noticed that in your question there are commands to install a custom built kernel. You probably failed to install a kernel, or maybe not. But then you started to be scared to install a stable kernel for Ubuntu dev release.

Comment: I tried to update the kernel as you said. Unfortunately the system crashed after rebooting. I got a black screen with 
"gave up waiting for root device ... ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/(big string) does not exist. Dropping to a shell!". Then it appears BusBox v.1.22.1 built-in shell (ash) with (initramfs) for taping commands.
I don't know absolutely what to do...

Comment: You could make a mistake and did not install some part of it. You can always boot with a previous kernel using grub menu.

Comment: Are you sure that I need only the five files you listed above?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Check that they install without errors.

Comment: No way, i tried once again the update of the kernel, there were no errors, and the system crashed again...

Comment: It is hard to tell what is wrong in you system tith this driver. You can wait till the release of 16.04 with this kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed the kernel v4.5 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/ on my Dell XPS 13 (9350) and wifi works fine now. Previously I had kernel v4.2, and tried installing v4.4 rc6 and rc7 without success (couldn't even start Ubuntu after the install).

Steps to follow:

```
mkdir /tmp
cd /tmp
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-image-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
reboot
```