# Partition problems!

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to install a dual boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop with Windows 10 already installed. I have a 250GB SSD hard drive and I partitioned 60GB in EXT4 for Ubuntu. I used a program called Partition Wizard (I know, I should have used GParted), and now I am having trouble.

When I try to install Ubuntu, it does not see any partitions. When I rebooted back to Windows to troubleshoot, I cannot get Partition Wizard to open unless I go into Services and restart Virtual Disk. When I do manage to open Partition Wizard, it won't allow me to do anything. If I try to make another partition or erase it, it just sort of sits there at 0%. Also, I cannot open Windows Disk Management as it says it's unable to connect to Virtual Disk and when I try to restart the computer, it just lingers on the "restarting" screen without actually restarting. I have to do a forced shut down. I also cannot access my external 2TB HDD or any USB flash drives through Windows.

I managed to download and install GParted onto a USB flash drive through a live version of Ubuntu but GParted does not show any partitions.

Any idea what the problem is or how to solve it?

[image]

[lsblk screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPLZA.jpg)

Comment: most likely cause is that you are booting your installer in Legacy mode. Legacy mode can not read a GPT partitioned disk.

Comment: My boot mode is set to UEIF and secure boot is set to "off"

Comment: Your setup is GPT. You must boot in UEFI mode. Once done, please show the output of `lsblk` from the Live CD before you start the installer. You can put that in the post above. I can see Partition Wizard correctly identifies the Ext4 partition.

Comment: I have added a 'lsblk' screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

I decided to reinstall Windows 10 because I was having so many problems with it and that fixed everything within Windows. I still could not get GParted or the Ubuntu installer to see any partitions on my SSD so did a little more Google research and found this answer and followed the instructions. It worked and I was able to successfully install Ubuntu without any further problems!

[Solution from a similar Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/a/743329)

Answer (score 0):

I created a dual boot system awhile ago. From memory I just used the Windows Disc Management tool to create and format a partition and after that I was able to install ubuntu on that from a bootable usb.

From your description of the problem it sounds like Partition Wizard might have got stuck part-way through the partitioning process and has caused some errors. Assuming you have already backed up your system, you could try using a bootable windows disc and selecting repair from the boot options. Or use system restore to go back to a point before you tried partitioning?

Worst case scenario is a reinstall of windows, but hopefully it's not that bad.

Update: I had a look at your screenshot. I'm not sure what the 16GB might be, but it looks like the 60GB partition you wanted is there, formatted as Ext4, so that bit is fine.

Comment: I added a screenshot of Partition Wizard. There is one partition that is 16MB  but no file system and no name. Any idea what that might be?