# Ubuntu live usb does not detect HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, hard-drive

I am trying to setup a dual boot system of windows pro 10 and ubuntu 16.04.1.
Currently I am stuck where I boot from my live usb in **"Try Ubuntu"** but I could not detect my hard drive at all. The live usb does not see the hard drive at all.

I had tried this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696413/ubuntu-installer-cant-find-any-disk-on-dell-xps-13-9350?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and switch SATA to ACHI mode from RAID but still I cannot see my drive at all. I did also a `sudo fdisk -l` but my 2Tb hard disk does not show up.

Comment: Open Disks and look there, if you see it click the triangle to mount it.

Comment: @c.s.cameron I could not see my disk. The size of /dev/sda which I think should be my disk does not have the same size as my hard disk of 1.9Tb

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I could not see my disk. My 1.9Tb is not showing up when I boot from my usb. However, I can boot nicely into Windows pro 10 and see all my partition.