# Dual boot Kubuntu/Win10 issues after replacing kde

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, grub-efi

I have been having nothing but issues trying to get Linux set up on my brand new Dell xps 15.

Had Kde neon user installed but it gave me too many fan and freezing issues so I deleted the partitions and have been trying to get kubuntu 18.04 lts set up as my development platform alongside windows 10 for gaming.

I etched it to a usb and when trying to install I would always get grub install dev/sda failed errors when chosing it while selecting partitions.
Every time I click on try instead of install it just freezes and I have to hard reboot.

I changed the path to dev/nvme0n1 because that is where my windows disk is and the install completed but during it's restart it froze and I had to hard reboot.

My disk shows they are no longer unallocated space but no matter what boot option I try I can not get it to start.  I have secure boot off , legacy roms enabled, UEFI and the efi inside ubuntu just loads a Dell system scan.

I can add pictures of bios and diskspace but what should I do? Everything online tells me to repair boot  but I can't access Ubuntu konsole to use sudo commands

Comment: With Dell you must update UEFI from Dell and update firmware for NVMe drive. And drive(s) have to be changed from RAID or Intel SRT to AHCI. Only install in UEFI boot mode and make sure Windows fast start up is off. If nVidia you will need nomodeset boot parameter. https://askubuntu.com/questions/696413/ubuntu-installer-cant-find-any-disk-on-dell-xps-13-9350/743329#743329

Comment: It's already been in AHCI I turned off fast startup as soon as I got the computer also updated drivers but no go and why did I have so many issues running kde neon and can't try ubuntu without it freezing

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &