# Dual booting ubuntu onto existing windows 10 parittion without grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have a laptop with windows 10 installed on it, and I want to dual boot ubuntu onto it. I've done this before once, but the install also installed GRUB, probably because I picked the "install alongside windows" option instead of manually installing to a partition. I would like to use MBR instead of GRUB, with no new partitions added.

I've looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader), which pretty much sums up what I want to do, but seeing as this article is 8 years old, is it still accurate? do I still have to jump through all the hoops of installing grub and setting a timeout of 0?

Comment: Partitions are either MBR(msdos) or gpt. Grub installs into the MBR for BIOS boot. But Windows 10 if preinstalled has to be UEFI with gpt partitioning & then Ubuntu needs to be UEFI also. Or is Windows 10 an upgrade from Windows 7 which usually was BIOS/MBR? Post this above: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: I don't have ubuntu installed currently, had to jump thought a few hoops a couple of years back to get rid of the grub installed. My windows is a UEFI install, confirmed through msinfo32. It was also a fresh install, not upgraded through windows 7.

Comment: What brand/model system and video card/chip? Some need UEFI settings or boot parameters. Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi 
 & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295

Comment: Dell xps 13 9350 with a i7-6560u, which has integrated iris 540 graphics. I think I should be fine with regrads to your last two links, but will what I want to work if I can just install ubuntu manually without a bootloader?

Comment: Dell needs drives changed to AHCI, but first install Windows AHCI drivers. https://askubuntu.com/questions/696413/ubuntu-installer-cant-find-any-disk-on-dell-xps-13-9350/743329#743329. Many Dells need UEFI update & if SSD, SSD firmware update. Make sure both UEFI fast boot & Windows fast startup are off.

Comment: I know I have to change my windows drive to ACHI, but after that, how should I install ubuntu so that I don't have to deal with grub? On another note, can I have my windows patition non ACHI, and my ubuntu partition ACHI so that there's a sort of "hidden" OS depending on which bios setting i'm on?

Comment: AHCI is a drive setting. And drive is the entire physical drive. Grub is both a menu and boot loader, so you have to have grub as boot loader. But can use UEFI as menu or install other menu like rEFInd.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi